# Peopleresults.aspx Showing the same picture for different people

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, user-profile-service, enterprise-search

Good day,

I have a problem with  peopleresult.aspx page every first time you search for a person it bring different people with the same picture until you refresh then the correct picture appears. Thanks in Advance. See below for picture.
[image]

Comment: Are you using custom display/item templates?

Comment: Yes I am for the Item_Person_Hover

Comment: Check the code in the custom template, maybe the problem is there (a variable initialized with that unique image and the overwritten)

Comment: I can't seem to find anything any problem. It seems to work fine on Chrome and Firefox